# Function that returns parameters C++

Tags: c++

Hello I have a little problem and I would be happy if you could tell me how to fix it.
So I have a function which is the realization like this :

```
int* getMytree()
```

The function should return three variables. The variables are defined as public.

How do I return the three parameters ?

Comment: If you need my advice, the function should be modular such that is calculates a single result. You can use passing by reference to modify the passed in parameters if you want.

Comment: The pass by reference approach looks like `void getMytree(int& a, int& b, int& c);`

Comment: @Mahmoud Fayez: if these parameters are related, chances are high that they share a good deal of the computation and splitting into separate functions would be a waste.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from wrapping three variables inside a `struct`

You can return a [*`std::tuple`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> getMytree(int id)
{
   // ....
   // a= , b= c=
   return std::make_tuple( a,b,c );
}
```

And then use [*`std::tie`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) with your *public* variables as :

```
 std::tie( var1, var2, var3 ) = getMytree() ;
```

Comment: you didn't mentioned that how return statement should look like?
return std::make_tuple(1,2,3);

Answer (score 2):

Sorry there's no way to explicitly return three values from a function as function can return only one value. However you could do two things

1) Encapsulate those three parameters in a struct and then make function to return that struct.

```
struct Book
{
int pages;
std::string name;
std::string author
};

Book myFunc ();  // This example is just for simplicity.
```

2) More simply pass pointers/references to three parameters you want the function to change.

```
void myFunc ( int& page, std::string &name, std::string &author );
```

Comment: Why define a struct by the name `book` and typedef it to `Book`? Seems a bit redundant to me.

Comment: Yes that's redundant. I said example is just to clarify myself w.r.t question asked...